# Include external jar while while creating .dll with ikvmc

Tags: java, jar, ikvm

I'm using ikvmc to convert my .jar file into a .NET library. The java project contains a linked library. While converting the file with the instruction `ikvmc subDir/compiledJar.jar` I get the following errors:

```
warning IKVMC0100: Class "com.sb.cl.Server" not found
warning IKVMC0100: Class "com.sb.cl.Session" not found
warning IKVMC0100: Class "com.sb.cl.Requirement" not found
warning IKVMC0100: Class "com.sb.cl.server.RemoteServerException" not found
warning IKVMC0100: Class "com.sb.cl.attribute.AttributeValue" not found
warning IKVMC0100: Class "com.sb.cl.attribute.Attribute" not found
warning IKVMC0100: Class "Cl.UDAValue" not found
warning IKVMC0111: Emitted java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in "clJavaAccess.LoginAndObtain.<init>(Ljava.lang.String;)V"
("com.sb.cl.server.Server")
warning IKVMC0111: Emitted java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in "clJavaAccess.LoginAndObtain.obtainCustomTabValue(ILjava.lang.String;)I"
("com.sb.cl.Session")
warning IKVMC0111: Emitted java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in "clJavaAccess.LoginAndObtain.login(Ljava.lang.String;Ljava.lang.String;)V"
("com.sb.cl.server.Server")
```

I altered the package names.

Obviously I am missing the resources for com.sb.cl.* here which are included in my project. How can I reference the .jar file used by `compiledJar.jar`? Or is there anyway to build `compiledJar.jar` "static" so that it will contain the needed .jar? I tried the options -externalresource, -resource and -reference (on ikvmc) yet, although all of them seem to be suited for other cases.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove all method and classes related to latest version of library , and change it to lower version of library of java , may it work , because I have same error like this and it work for me